# Reactive Extensions combining two IObservables into one

Tags: system.reactive

I'm trying to combine an IObservable that contains request information with an IObservable that contains response information.  Both the request and response information contain an Id and a timestamp in the form of a DateTime.  The Id on the Request will match the Id on the Response.

I need to combine the two streams based on Id and calculate the time elapsed between the Request's timestamp and the Response's timestamp.  What is the best way to accomplish this:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could join by coincidence.

```
from request in requests             // 1
join response in responses           // 2
on responses.Where(response => response.Id == request.Id) // 1,3
equals Observable.Empty<Unit>()      // 2
where request.Id == response.Id      // 4
select response.Time - request.Time  // 5
```

Think of it like this:

1. Create a window for each request.
2. Project every response into every request window.
3. When a response matches a request, close that request window.
4. For each request, ignore all responses that do not match.
5. Project the time difference for the response that does match.

**Update:**

Request windows are opened by `from` and closed by `on`.

Response windows are opened by `join` and closed by `equals`. The response duration specified by `equals` is `Empty`, thus responses aren't actually windows - they are treated as point events and simply projected once into whatever request windows are currently open.

#3 requires a `Where` operator because it defines the duration of each request; i.e., it indicates when a request window closes, which is when a response with a matching ID arrives.

#4 is required because of #3. Think about it - we're cross-joining every response with every request window that's currently open. Request windows only close when a matching response arrives. That means every response that doesn't match is paired with every request, but you only care about the last response - the one that matches.

Comment: Relevant video on "Join By Coincidence" on Channel9 http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Programming-Streams-of-Coincidence-with-Join-and-GroupJoin-for-Rx

Comment: Dave Sexton - can you elaborate on which bit(s) of linq code accomplish which of the 5 items you listed?  Can you elaborate on why the two similar-looking "where" clauses are necessary and what each does?

Comment: Nice. I didn't think of this! Great answer.

Comment: Updated to include the requested details.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have concurrent requests, Zip is probably the operator you are looking for:

http://rxmarbles.com/#zip

Zip will combine two observables in a single sequence that produces elements at a rate that is defined by the slowest observable being combined.

In case you have concurrent requests, you should probably try a different approach that does not require you to combine the two observables. You could for instance store the request ID and DateTime in a ConcurrentDictionary and subscribe to the responses observable where you lookup for the corresponding request from the ConcurrentDictionary (don't forget to remove the entry after reading it).

Comment: I can see how the zip approach would work in a simple case where the requests and the replies are made to "line up" in 1:1 correlation in their respective streams, but this is not the case I have unfortunately.